# Reading image using impersonation

Tags: wpf, impersonation, bitmapimage

I'm trying to read an image from a location that has restricted access and return it to a property in my wpf application.  Problem is that I can't seem to get around this error:
`A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

Here's the code:

```
public BitmapImage GetImage()
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    var impersonation = new ImpersonationManager(Resources.Username,
                Resources.Domain,
                Resources.Password);
    using (impersonation.SafeTokenHandle)
    {
        using (var newId = new WindowsIdentity(impersonation.SafeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
        {
            using (newId.Impersonate())
            {
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"\\restrictedpath\\to\\image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
                bitmap.EndInit();
            }
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

The windows user I am running this app under does NOT have access to `restrictedpath`, but the creds I'm using for impersonation are good, and otherwise the impersonation works great.   The `ImpersonationManager` is just a wrapper.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: The URI won't work that way. It needs to have a drive letter like `"C:\\restrictedpath\\to\\image.jpg"`, or better `@"C:\restrictedpath\to\image.jpg"`. This does however not explain the exception.

Comment: @Clemens Hmm, not true- UNC paths work just fine... otherwise how would you ever access a shared drive that wasn't mapped?  And this code works fine minus the exception. If I have access to that drive all is good.  Totally agree on the `@` I patched this example in from the real code and missed that.

Comment: If it was a UNC path, you should have written `@"\\restrictedpath\to\image.jpg"`, where `restrictedpath` is the server name, right?

Comment: Yep that's right.  Like I said I boiled the example out of the real code and forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone runs into this, I did figure it out.  I had to open a stream to read the file in and then assign that to the bitmap's stream source:

```
public BitmapImage GetImage()
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    var impersonation = new ImpersonationManager(Resources.Username,
                Resources.Domain,
                Resources.Password);
    using (impersonation.SafeTokenHandle)
    using (var newId = new WindowsIdentity(impersonation.SafeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
    using (newId.Impersonate())
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"\\restrictedpath\\to\\image.jpg"))
        {
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze();
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

That and the `bitmap.Freeze()` took care of my issues.